# How could I serialize and deserialize a prefix trie?

Tags: java, algorithm, autocomplete, tree, trie

I was brushing up on some data structures and implemented a working prefix trie. I’m trying to understand the usage of this data structure at scale. In my implementation, all my dummy data is loaded fully into memory. Let’s say I have 5 million words in my prefix trie, how does this actually work in application?

I’m trying to understand if I want to do an autocomplete implementation, do I type a phrase and then read from disk node by node? Even if that is the case, I’m trying to understand how that works from a high-level.

Comment: In a day and age where main memory is routinely measured in **billions** of bytes, a mere five _million_ words is probably not too much to keep all in memory.  If it were me, that's the way I'd go.

Comment: Let’s say 5 trillion then hypothetically. I’m trying to understand how cache eviction policies work with prefix tries and disk

Comment: Well, the relationship between the Trie and disk can be whatever you care to program it to be.  You certainly could devise an on-disk representation of a Trie that could be searched with no more than one node in memory at a time, if that's your pleasure.

Comment: I’m confused on how I could implement the theoretical one node case. Basically like having an LRU cache of K nodes each each level of tree. But then I’m wondering how I would deserialize a subtree from the data I have written to disk. I think the most confusing piece to me is serializing a subtree (and appending to already serialized tree) and deserializing a subtree to load up into the trie that exists in memory.

Comment: Don't think about deserializing whole _subtrees_, just individual _nodes_.  And forget about caching _X_ number of nodes _per level_; just have an LRU cache of _nodes_, period, and let the LRU algorithm take care of which nodes stay and which go. Does that sound less confusing?

Comment: Ok, so I’ve been trying to draw this out on the board. Let’s say I have LRU cache policy with max of 3 nodes at the root and I’m about to insert a new string that will exceed the 3 node max at a particular level. Does it seem reasonable to get all valid phrases/words from the node that is about to be removed and persist that into the DB? Then when I get a cache miss, I can query DB to grab top 3 words that start with a particular phrase and run each of those through the trie insert?

Comment: Guess I’d be confused why it’s not LRU cache on a level basis, but I guess that would probably make more sense actually.. Can you explain when something would get evicted (under a very low policy) when I insert something and the max is exceeded (as a whole)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196023/discussion-between-john-lippson-and-kevin-anderson).